# Передача input разных классов

Tags: javascript, post

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста. В приведённом ниже коде есть два `input` с одинаковым именем `"street_number"`, но заключённые в разные `div`. Скрипты адекватно передают значения в `val`. Но при передаче в БД, вместо значения передаётся имя `input` - `"street_number"`. Изменить имя `input` не получается, т.к. гугловский `geocomplete` передаёт значение в это имя. Вопрос: как передать в БД значение `input` с одинаковым именем, но принадлежащие разным классам? Ошибка в обработчике: `$street_number = $_POST['street_number'];`  Просьба сильно не пинать.

```
<div class="location">
 <div class="departureAddress">
  <input type="text" name="departureAddress" class="geocomplete">

   <script defer async>
   $(function(){
     $(".geocomplete").geocomplete({
       details: ".departureAddress",
       detailsScope: '.location',
       types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
     });
     $("#find").click(function(){
       $(this).parents(".location").find(".geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
     });
   });
   </script>

  <input name="street_number" type="text" value="">

 </div>
</div>  

<div class="location2">
 <div class="deliveryAddress">
 <input type="text" name="deliveryAddress" class="geocomplete2">

  <script defer async>
  $(function(){
    $(".geocomplete2").geocomplete({
      details: ".deliveryAddress",
      detailsScope: '.location2',
      types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
    });
    $("#submit").click(function(){
      $(this).parents(".location").submit(".geocomplete2").trigger("geocode");
    });
  });
  </script>

 <input name="street_number" type="text" value="">

 </div>
</div>

<p>
<input class="btn-to-send" id="find" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
</p>
```

Comment: Это правильный код? Ваш js не соответствует вашему html

Comment: Возможно JS не совсем адекватен, но он работает. Взято было несколько кодов у гугла для разных задач

Comment: Стандартный POST два поля с одинаковым именем никогда не передаст. Единственное решение при передаче формы доработать форму собственным JS скриптом, который переименует поля или скопирует значения из них в отдельные input type=hidden или вообще сам сформирует запрос к серверу где назовет поля по разному

Comment: Спасибо. Обращение к серверу не вариант. Гугл всё-равно отдаст только стандартные переменные.(. Наверное лучший вариант с переименованием полей.

Comment: @Владимир , Mike говорит про перенос значений в переименованные input при передаче на ваш сервер, а не на сервер google